# Should I use singleton, static Class or `shared` for connecting to database from many classes?

Tags: database, class, singleton, d, static-classes

I am writing Apps that connect to DB. I need be able use DataBase connection from many classes.

```
class Database
{
  auto MyConnection = new Connection("..."); // create connection

  void calc()
  {
    MyConnection.query("..."); // use it
  }
}
```

But I need to get access to `MyConnection` from every class? Should I do `Database` class `static`? Or maybe I should use Singleton patter? Or make `MyConnection` as `shared`?

And for example what about config? Is it's good idea to make it for example `shared`?

Or for example can I declare connection statement globally before main? Like:

```
MySQLPool MyConnection;

void main()
{
//...
}
```

and then initiate `MyConnection` from `static this() { }` or from DB class?

Comment: Why not pass the `Database` around? It might seem like a lot of work, but ultimately your code will be better off.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the Repository pattern as described here: http://web.archive.org/web/20150404154203/https://www.remondo.net/repository-pattern-example-csharp/

You should be thinking about the architecture of your application.  I you go with this approach then I would have a class called db (not static and not singleton) with methods like:

```
Read
Scaler
Execute
Insert
etc
```

Your repository layer should be separate to your domain layer.

In my experience this makes the code testable.